Navigation Issue in React Native: "NAVIGATE action not handled by any navigator
I'm experiencing an issue with navigation in my React Native app using React Navigation. When trying to navigate to a screen within a nested navigator, I'm getting the following error:
ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ExploreStack","params":{"screen":"Roaster"}} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'ExploreStack'?

I'm using the following libraries:

@react-navigation/native: "^6.0.0"

@react-navigation/bottom-tabs: "^6.0.0"

@react-navigation/stack: "^6.0.0"

react-native-vector-icons: "^8.0.0"


Here is my current setup:
ExploreScreen.js:
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const ExploreScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenTimeTracking')}>
        <Ionicons name="time" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Screen Time Tracking</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ApplicationProcess')}>
        <Ionicons name="apps" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Application Process</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Bookings')}>
        <Ionicons name="book" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Bookings</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Roaster')}>
        <Ionicons name="calendar" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Roaster</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DigitalPersonalFileLite')}>
        <Ionicons name="folder-open" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Digital Personal File Lite</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ELearning')}>
        <Ionicons name="school" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>E-learning</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Imprint')}>
        <Ionicons name="information-circle-outline" size={24} color="#000" />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Imprint</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  },
  item: {
    width: '90%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
  text: {
    marginLeft: 16,
    fontSize: 16,
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default ExploreScreen;

AppNavigator.js:
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

// Import screens
import DashboardScreen from '../screens/DashboardScreen';
import ExploreScreen from '../screens/ExploreScreen';
import ScreenTimeTrackingScreen from '../screens/ScreenTimeTrackingScreen';
import ApplicationProcessScreen from '../screens/ApplicationProcessScreen';
import BookingsScreen from '../screens/BookingsScreen';
import RoasterScreen from '../screens/RoasterScreen';
import DigitalPersonalFileLiteScreen from '../screens/DigitalPersonalFileLiteScreen';
import ELearningScreen from '../screens/ELearningScreen';
import ImprintScreen from '../screens/ImprintScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const ExploreStack = createStackNavigator();

const ExploreStackScreen = () => (
  <ExploreStack.Navigator>
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="ScreenTimeTracking" component={ScreenTimeTrackingScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="ApplicationProcess" component={ApplicationProcessScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="Bookings" component={BookingsScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="Roaster" component={RoasterScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="DigitalPersonalFileLite" component={DigitalPersonalFileLiteScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="ELearning" component={ELearningScreen} />
    <ExploreStack.Screen name="Imprint" component={ImprintScreen} />
  </ExploreStack.Navigator>
);

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'Dashboard') {
              iconName = 'ios-home';
            } else if (route.name === 'Explore') {
              iconName = 'ios-search';
            } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
              iconName = 'ios-settings';
            }

            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default AppNavigator;

When I press any button in ExploreScreen, I expect to navigate to the corresponding screen (e.g., ScreenTimeTracking, ApplicationProcess, etc.). However in get
ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ExploreStack","params":{"screen":"Roaster"}} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'ExploreStack'?

But the screen does not change. I believe the navigation is not correctly handled by the navigator. Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Your screen's name is Explore, not ExploreStack - you're navigating to ExploreStack somewhere but haven't posted the code.

I was able to resolve the error.
Instead of nesting in my DashboardScreen.js which contains the EXploreScreen.js, i was rather doing that in AppNavigator.js.

When you are in one the tab navigator screen, navigation prop will only have access to the screens that are in tab navigator which are "Dashboard", "Explore" and "Settings".
When i used drawer navigation in one of my projects, I faced the same issue and then i found the actions in react navigation.
In your case you can use something like this
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('ScreenTimeTracking'));

For reference you can look in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions

Second option:
I have looked more into it
You should use Stack navigator as your main navigator and nest tab navigator onto it as in their official documentation.

function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

In the above example, the Home component contains a tab navigator. The Home component is also used for the Home screen in your stack navigator inside the App component. So here, a tab navigator is nested inside a stack navigator
Then if you want to manually change tab you can use
import { TabActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const jumpToAction = TabActions.jumpTo('Profile', { user: 'Satya' });

navigation.dispatch(jumpToAction);

You just have to make sure that if you are navigating to a screen the current screen is of the same navigator otherwise it will give error.
for reference
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

all the buttons when clicked on produce this error: `ERROR The action 'REPLACE' with payload {"name":"Imprint"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'Imprint'?`

I have edited my answer if it can help.
